# Syncing data from server to app without REST API web service call

Tags: android, synchronization, android-sqlite

I want to sync my huge data in to my mobile local storage, without using Rest API web service call from server.

I have already tried once POC for rest api ws call from android mobile sqlite database sync from server using json format request and response. that time, am getting some performance issue come while huge data synchronizing from server to mobile sqlite database.thats why, searching for some other solution, without rest api, i want to sync the data from server to mobile.

Note: I have refered couchbase database for the same. it recommended for cross platform developing.
I am asking example like Firebase

any help.
Thanks Advance Guys

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "recommended for cross platform developing." ? Couchbase Mobile is available for native platforms. https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.1/introduction.html